# Can we check if a CA certificate is installed on Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, certificate, ca

I am developing a **Google Chrome Extension**.I want to detect if my **private CA certificate** is imported or not. From there I can decide whether to provide instructions for installations. Is it possible using chrome extension api?

**chrome.platformKeys** and **chrome.enterprise.platformKeys** seems to help to find  client certificates.

Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: chrome.enterprise.platformKeys.getCertificates(string tokenId, function callback), Returns the list of all client certificates available from the given token. Can be used to check for the existence and expiration of client certificates that are usable for a certain authentication. this might going to help you.

Comment: What is the certificate for? Maybe you can try to make a connection that requires it, and check for a specific failure.

Comment: `chrome.enterprise.platformKeys`, by the way, is not for that and only available on enterprise installs of Chrome OS.